# How to send put and delete HTTP requests from ejs to express.js

Tags: html, node.js, express, http, ejs

How can I make a form to send PUT and DELETE HTTP requests from an ejs file to an express.js API?

Comment: are you getting any errors? Which approach did you try? Is there an example?

Comment: In the GET and POST requests on html or ejs you just write a form and you send the request. But idk what to do when I want to send PUT or DELETE requests.